# Need to take care the junk values while converting varchar to datetime using SSIS

Tags: ssis

Within my package, I have a column that has text in `ddMMyyyy` format.
I need to convert to DATETIME which I do via a Derived Column Transformation.

The column sometimes contains junk values like ABC, NR, etc and then the package fails.

How I can take care of such values and show them as NULL in my destination table? I have tried using it in Derived Column Expression but the package execution fails with "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."

e.g. `(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(SampleDate,3,2) + "/" + (LEFT(SampleDate,2) + "/" + RIGHT(SampleDate,4)))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [isdate function in ssis derived component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236505/isdate-function-in-ssis-derived-component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark the derived column to ignore errors and it will remove invalid values and make them nulls.  That will be the easiest way in an expression of a derived column.

Open Derived Column click "Configure Error Output" and change Error to "Ignore Error"

[image]